# Conditionally fill a partially filled pandas dataframe by index value

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe that is partially filled dataframe that I am trying to fill, I will need to write an if else statement and wanted to use the index to fill each position, the values in between each filled position will use a will be calculated at different rates as the gaps between each filled position are different :

**Update: There are a total of 41 rows, I have information for rows 0,12,26,41.  I want to divide the difference between of rows 0,12 by the number of rows with missing data then add that amount.**

```
Ex.
9-7 = 2   
2/11 = .182
Then add:
7.182
7.364
7.546
```

...

```
dates.iloc[0:14,0:3]
    Date    Unemployment
0   2007-01-01  7
1   2007-02-01  
2   2007-03-01  
3   2007-04-01  
4   2007-05-01  
5   2007-06-01  
6   2007-07-01  
7   2007-08-01  
8   2007-09-01  
9   2007-10-01  
10  2007-11-01  
11  2007-12-01  
12  2008-01-01  9
13  2008-02-01  
...
```

Comment: Can you post expected output also ?

Comment: @PrinceFrancis I added an update to hopefully better understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for `interpolate`:

```
# make sure your Date column is datetime type
df.set_index('Date').interpolate('index').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         Date  Unemployment
0  2007-01-01      7.000000
1  2007-02-01      7.169863
2  2007-03-01      7.323288
3  2007-04-01      7.493151
4  2007-05-01      7.657534
5  2007-06-01      7.827397
6  2007-07-01      7.991781
7  2007-08-01      8.161644
8  2007-09-01      8.331507
9  2007-10-01      8.495890
10 2007-11-01      8.665753
11 2007-12-01      8.830137
12 2008-01-01      9.000000
13 2008-02-01      9.000000
```